# Quais prefixos de propriedades CSS são compatíveis com o Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Com [lançamento do Windows 10](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/features) a Microsoft acabou aposentando o Internet Explorer, alterando o navegador padrão para o [Microsoft Edge](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/microsoft-edge).

Para suportar propriedades CSS que ainda não foram [padronizadas pelo W3C<sup>en</sup>](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#drafts), os navegadores implementam prefixos exclusivos para suportar essas novas propriedades ainda incompletas. O Internet Explorer [usa o prefixo `-ms-*`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm).

O Edge utiliza esses mesmos prefixos ou algum novo prefixo foi criado para ele (algo parecido com `-ed-*` por exemplo)?

Comment: Deve utilizar o mesmo prefixo, afinal `-ms-` refere-se a Microsoft e não ao Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só complementando a outra resposta, desde 2014 a Microsoft tem trabalhado mais intensamente para conseguir exibir conteúdo Web nos seus browsers. E foi observado que muitas páginas, principalmente as mobile, tem usado somente o prefixo `-webkit-` e não outros. Portanto, eles passaram a também considerar propriedades que usam o prefixo `-webkit-` (fonte: [The Mobile Web should just work for everyone](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/the-mobile-web-should-just-work-for-everyone)). Isso é até possível observar no gráfico da outra resposta.

A Microsoft disponibilizou também o site [Status da plataforma](https://developer.microsoft.com/pt-br/microsoft-edge/status/) que dá informações sobre o status de desenvolvimento dos recursos CSS.

Quanto ao uso em si dos prefixos CSS, deve-se procurar usar todos os possíveis (`-webkit-`, `-ms-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`) e também, quando possível, fazer uso do recurso `@supports`.

Para ver mais informações sobre isso, escrevi [um post que aborda prefixos CSS no Edge](https://web.archive.org/web/20160619034806/https://talkitbr.com/2015/08/19/prefixos-css-no-microsoft-edge/).

Answer (score 5):

Propriedades prefixadas existentes que são extremamente populares permanecerá até que tenham suporte nativo, mas a Microsoft Edge não será a introdução de um novo sistema de prefixo para recursos. Em vez disso, eles vão usar sinalizadores de recurso (como o Chrome e Firefox para recursos experimentais no lado do cliente, em vez de lado o desenvolvedor).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft ainda utiliza o prefixo -ms-*. Os estilos suportados pelo Edge estão publicados nesse link: 
https://dev.modern.ie/platform/documentation/apireference/cssstyles/

Lá dá para ver que existem -ms-* e -webkit-* implementados no engine.