# Console Edge? Existe?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Existe console no Edge? Como abrir e usar?

Tem algumas coisas que preciso consertar no CSS do site no Edge e sem console não consigo saber.

Comment: Acredito que seja o mesmo do IE, F12.

Comment: Obrigado, não tinha testado, deu certo!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe sim, a tecla de atalho seria o <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Veja a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide) sobre o funcionamento.

Comment: E qual o prefixo do Microssoft Edge? Continua sendo o -ms do internet explorer?

Comment: Veja [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79964/quais-prefixos-de-propriedades-css-s%C3%A3o-compat%C3%ADveis-com-o-edge) resposta sobre os prefixos no Edge.